# Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type '[String]'

Tags: swift, string, core-data, casting

I have done some digging but I'm unable to find the answer to the above.

Here is my ListViewControllerCode:

```
import UIKit

class ListsViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    let viewController = ListNameViewController()
    let rootVC = RootListsViewController()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var item1 = [ListItem]()
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! as NSIndexPath
        let destViewController = segue.destination as? RootListsViewController
        var item1Array : ListItem
        item1Array = item1[indexPath.row]
        destViewController?.item1 = item1Array.name!
    }
}
```

Here is my RootListViewController code (Where I'm passing the value too):

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class RootListsViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var titleName = ""
    var newListItem : String = ""
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var item1 = [String]()
    
   //other code...

}
```

So I understand that the data item1.name is coming from CoreData which is set as a string value.
I then want to cast this to work in an array so I can display it in a table view. I have tried converting this in many ways but no luck.

Anyone know the answer?

Comment: But you requesting 1 item, not array of Items

Answer (score 3):

Problem is here

```
destViewController?.item1 = item1Array.name!
```

Change to

```
destViewController?.item1 = [item1Array.name!]
```

or safely

```
destViewController?.item1 = item1Array.name != nil ? [item1Array.name!] : []
```

or

```
destViewController?.item1 = [item1Array.name].compactMap { $0 }
```

Comment: Dont use force unwrap, bad practice

Comment: Why it is a bad practice: You are ordering the compiler "if anything is wrong here, then please please crash my program". And next week is posting again "why is my app crashing" and the answer is "because you used ! and that means you ask for it to crash".

Answer (score 1):

A string and an array of strings are totally different things. You can't cast a string to an array of strings, that doesn't make any sense.

You can obviously create an array containing a single string.

Some other thing where you are just confusing yourself: item is an array of ListItem, while itemArray is a single ListItem. That doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very usefull!